# How do i allow access to a single file in my root directory?

Tags: htaccess

I want to register my website (which is a wordpress site) with the google webmaster search console. This requires me to upload a verification html, but access to that is prohibited by the rules in htaccess which wordpress sets. Is there an easy workaround for this? I'm not that familiar with .htaccess, but i have ssh access to it and can change it if you tell me what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such rule set by WordPress. If I create a file generic.html in my root WP folder and then go to www.mypage.com/generic.html the file will open.

What exactly happens when you put the file into your root folder (next to wp-config.php)?

In any case, if there are rules in .htaccess that are causing some form of redirect or denial you could just remove those for a few minutes while Google pokes at your page to check for the file. The check only needs to happen once after all.

An alternative is if you already have the page in your Google Analytics account you can choose "Alternate methods" on the Webmaster Tools screen that tells you to upload the .html file and that will just prove your ownership from your Google Analytics account.

Comment: I chose the analytics method. I'm not sure about the 'google only checks once', since, if you choose verification via html tag, it explicitly tells you not to remove the tags as it will periodically check them.